# Simple calculator program in Java. No. of integers read and Average

Tags: java, calculator, integer

I have a task that requires me to print out the following quantities:

I need to write a java program that can calculate:
1. the number of integers read in
2. the average value—which need not be an integer!

My final output should look like:

```
$ javac SimpleCalc 
$ java SimpleCalc 3 4 6 8 1 
5
8
4.4 
7
```

I know i need to use a scanner class to read then as the user inputs then, i dont know how to make it display a count. I think that i can work this out,  i can compute the average by adding up the numbers and divide the toal by the number of integers entered.

However its my first time writing a program, and this is doing my head in. Any help would be appreciated, ill even accept pseudocode if it helps me work out how to approach this.

Comment: Try something, don't worry if that is wrong. Try solving the problems you encounter and post those that you are unable to solve. That way you will get very good answers. The question in its current form will most likely to be closed or ignored by the community

Comment: In addition to Nivas comment, divide your project into three catrgories: program execution, creating GUI and reading given values, create the business logic (calculation of different arithmetics). I'm sure the biggest challenge for you will be the middle part of your project.

Comment: See [Starting Writing a Program](http://www.patriciashanahan.com/beginner.html).  I highly recommend following each of the steps outlined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are supposed to use the arguments of the `main` function:

```
public class PrintArgs {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i<args.length; ++i) {
          System.out.println("Args " + (i + 1) + " is " + args[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Save this class in a file called `PrintArgs.java` and compile it using `javac`:

```
$ javac PrintArgs.java
```

Run the generated class file using `java`:

```
$ java PrintArgs hello world
Args 1 is hello
Args 2 is world

$ java PrintArgs 3 4 6 8 1 
Args 1 is 3
Args 2 is 4
Args 3 is 6
Args 4 is 8
Args 5 is 1
```

Now you know how to read input from the user. To convert a `String` to `int`, use the `parseInt` method of the `Integer` class:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt("980");
System.out.println(100 + i); // => 1080
```

Now you know how to write your calculator program!

Comment: +1 - Nice answer leading the OP in the right direction, without actually doing it for him.

Comment: Thankyou, you explained it 100 times easier than my lab teacher did

Comment: However just one more question, why would i need to use the parseInt method?

Comment: @syncoroll You need to convert the `String` arguments of `main` to `int` values before you could add them, divide them etc.

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need a scanner in solving this. What you need is :

- Understanding of 'main method'
- Understanding of array and 'varargs'
- Understanding of parsing a string into another Object like Double or Integer
- Simple math (i believe you possess this)

If this is homework, your teacher ask you to read what i mention above.

Answer (score 1):

As I remember all you arguments are passed and stored in program in the variable that you `main` function expose:

```
public class Echo 
{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for (String s: args) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

So all is in your `string[] args`. This is array (the first is your program path and file), it has something like "Count()" method (don't remember), then you need to parse them to numbers using some wrapper, like `Integer.Parse(args[2])`.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

Answer (score -3):

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
   // 1. the number of integers read in

    int len = str.length

   //2. the average value


       int sum = 0;
       int avg = 0;
       for(int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++)
       { 
          sum = sum + str[i];
       }
       avg = sum/len ;
}
```

Comment: Just posting code doesn't really help the OP learn does it. Also, your code doesn't even make any sense.

Comment: I feel the code is self-explanatory as I have put the questions as comments.

Comment: And also since i read many of the posts before me have already explained about "public static void main(String args[])" and the use of array, I felt its redundant to repeat the same thing again.