# Calculate average in java

Tags: java, for-loop, count, average

**EDIT: I've written code for the average but I don't know how to make it so that it also uses `int`s from my `args.length` rather than the array.**

I need to write a java program that can calculate:

1. the number of integers read in
2. the average value – which need not be an integer!

NOTE: I don't want to calculate the average from the array but the integers in the `args`.

Currently I have written this:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<args.length -1; ++i)
    count++;
    System.out.println(count);
}
    
int nums[] = new int[] { 23, 1, 5, 78, 22, 4};
double result = 0; //average will have decimal point
for(int i=0; i < nums.length; i++){
    result += nums[i];
}
System.out.println(result/count)
```

Can anyone guide me in the right direction? Or give an example that guides me in the right way to shape this code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: args.length already contains your `count`, no need for the first for loop. Whats your question? Are you asking for improvements? Does your code work? Do you want to know how to transform `args[]` to an `int`-array?

Comment: `int count = args.length;` to get number of arguments ..

Comment: Is these two codes related or not ? Because in 2nd for loop you are using count.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993060/simple-calculator-program-in-java-no-of-integers-read-and-average/

Comment: Sorry i wasnt clear,  Ive written code for the average, but i dont know how to make it so that it also uses ints from my args.length rather than the array

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just some minor modification to your code will do (with some var renaming for clarity) :

```
double sum = 0; //average will have decimal point

for(int i=0; i < args.length; i++){
   //parse string to double, note that this might fail if you encounter a non-numeric string
   //Note that we could also do Integer.valueOf( args[i] ) but this is more flexible
   sum += Double.valueOf( args[i] ); 
}

double average = sum/args.length;

System.out.println(average );
```

Note that the loop can also be simplified:

```
for(String arg : args){
   sum += Double.valueOf( arg );
}
```

Edit: the OP seems to want to use the `args` array. This seems to be a String array, thus updated the answer accordingly.

**Update**:

As zoxqoj correctly pointed out, integer/double overflow is not taken care of in the code above. Although I assume the input values will be small enough to not have that problem, here's a snippet to use for really large input values:

```
BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.ZERO;
for(String arg : args){
  sum = sum.add( new BigDecimal( arg ) );
}
```

This approach has several advantages (despite being somewhat slower, so don't use it for time critical operations):

- Precision is kept, with double you will gradually loose precision with the number of math operations (or not get exact precision at all, depending on the numbers)
- The probability of overflow is practically eliminated. Note however, that a `BigDecimal` might be bigger than what fits into a `double` or `long`.

Comment: If i was to use args.lengths instead of nums.length what would i do to "sum += nums[i];" ?

Comment: @syncoroll Rereading your updated question I also updated my answer.

Comment: integer overflow is not taken care of

Comment: @zuxqoj That's true but I doubt this will be a problem here and I'd rather like to keep the example simple. I'll add another example though.

Comment: You should check if 0 == args.length, if you don't do this then you  you get "division by zero" on line double average = sum/args.length; when args.length is 0.

Comment: @MariusŽilėnas you're right and there are probably still a couple of further errors that might occur, but for simplicity's sake and in the case of the OP those are omitted and left for the implementor to handle.

Comment: sum += Double.valueOf( args );  should be sum += Double.valueOf( arg );

Comment: @Andromeda you're right, I fixed it in both snippets.

Answer (score 4):

```
int values[] = { 23, 1, 5, 78, 22, 4};

int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    sum += values[i];

double average = ((double) sum) / values.length;
```

Answer (score 2):

This

```
for (int i = 0; i<args.length -1; ++i)
    count++;
```

basically computes `args.length` again, just incorrectly (loop condition should be `i<args.length`). Why not just use `args.length` (or `nums.length`) directly instead?

Otherwise your code seems OK. Although it looks as though you wanted to read the input from the command line, but don't know how to convert that into an array of numbers - is this your real problem?

Answer (score 1):

It seems old thread, but Java has evolved since then & introduced Streams & Lambdas in Java 8. So might help everyone who want to do it using Java 8 features.

- In your case, you want to convert args which is String[] into double
  or int. You can do this using `Arrays.stream(<arr>)`. Once you have stream of String array elements, you can use `mapToDouble(s -> Double.parseDouble(s))` which will convert stream of Strings into    stream of doubles.
- Then you can use `Stream.collect(supplier, accumulator, combiner)` to calculate average if you want to control incremental calculation yourselves. Here is [some good example](http://itsallbinary.com/javadoc-examples/java/docs/api/examples/java/util/stream/java.util.stream.Stream.html#collectjava_util_function_Supplier-java_util_function_BiConsumer-java_util_function_BiConsumer).
- If you don't want to incrementally do average, you can directly use Java's `Collectors.averagingDouble()` which directly calculates and returns average. some [examples here](http://itsallbinary.com/javadoc-examples/java/docs/api/examples/java/util/stream/java.util.stream.Collectors.html#averagingDoublejava_util_function_ToDoubleFunction).

Answer (score 0):

```
 System.out.println(result/count)
```

you can't do this because result/count is not a String type, and System.out.println() only takes a String parameter. perhaps try:

```
double avg = (double)result / (double)args.length
```

Answer (score 0):

for 1. the number of integers read in, you can just use length property of array like :

```
int count = args.length
```

which gives you no of elements in an array.
And 2. to calculate average value :
 you are doing in correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<args.length -1; ++i)
    count++;
System.out.println(count);

 }
```

you can just

```
int count = args.length;
```

The average is the sum of your args divided by the number of your args.

```
int res = 0;
int count = args.lenght;

for (int a : args)
{
res += a;
}
res /= count;
```

you can make this code shorter too, i'll let you try and ask if you need help!

This is my first answerso tell me if something wrong!

Comment: I got an error for using args. "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type String to int"

Comment: Note that `res /= count` will do integer division and thus would most certainly yield the wrong result (the OP states that the average may contain decimal points).

Comment: @syncoroll You didn't tell us what `args` actually is - thus it might be assumed it is `int[] args`. Most likely you have `String[] args` (it's a `main` method, right?) - thus you'd have to change the for loop to `for( String a : args)` and call `res += Integer.parseInt( a)` inside.

Comment: You know, i won't test code for your homework! This is just a way of doing it, an algorithm.. it should work, it depends on the type of your vars..

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the integers from the command line args, you'll need something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] nums = new int[args.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        try {
            nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.err.println("Invalid argument");
        }
    }

    // averaging code here
}
```

As for the actual averaging code, others have suggested how you can tweak that (so I won't repeat what they've said).

Edit: actually it's probably better to just put it inside the above loop and not use the `nums` array at all

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to show you 2 ways. If you don't need a lot of stats in your project simply implement following.

```
public double average(ArrayList<Double> x) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (double aX : x) sum += aX;
    return (sum / x.size());
}
```

If you plan on doing a lot of stats might as well not reinvent the wheel. So why not check out http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/stat.html

You'll fall into true luv!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainTwo{
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        double[] Average = new double[5];
        Average[0] = 4;
        Average[1] = 5;
        Average[2] = 2;
        Average[3] = 4;
        Average[4] = 5;
        double sum = 0;
        if (Average.length > 0) {
            for (int x = 0; x < Average.length; x++) {
                sum+=Average[x];
                System.out.println(Average[x]);
            }
            System.out.println("Sum is " + sum);
            System.out.println("Average is " + sum/Average.length);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// question: let, Take 10 integers from keyboard using loop and print their average value on the screen.
// here they ask user to input 10 integars using loop and average those numbers.so the correct answer in my perspective with java is below:-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class averageValueLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
                sum = sum + sc.nextInt();
            }

            double average = sum / 10;
            System.out.println("Average is " + average);

        }

    }

}
```