# Calculating averages in Java?

Tags: java, syntax, average

I created a program for `TestScores` and `ScoreException` and now I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the averages of the scores. Here are my codes when I wrote the averages code it spawned a no suitable method found for the string

`TestScores`

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class TestScore
{
 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
  {
  int[] id = {1234, 2345, 3456, 4567, 5678};
  int[] score = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
  String scoreString = new String();
  final int HIGHLIMIT = 100;
  String inString, outString = "";
  for(int x = 0; x < id.length; ++x)
  {  
      inString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
        "Enter score for student id number: " + id[x]);
      score[x] = Integer.parseInt(inString);
      try
      {
         if(score[x] > HIGHLIMIT)
         {
            scoreString = "Score over " + HIGHLIMIT;
            throw (new ScoreException(scoreString));
         }  
      }
      catch(ScoreException e)
      {  
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());  
         score[x] = 0;
      }
      }
   for(int x = 0; x < id.length; ++x)
     outString = outString + "ID #" + id[x] + "  Score " +
          score[x] + "\n";
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outString); 
}
}
```

And my `ScoreException` code

```
public class ScoreException extends Exception
 {
  public ScoreException(String s)
  {
    super(s);
  }
 }
```

This is what I had for my average code, but it didn't come out correctly

```
int score[] = new score[] { 45, 98 ,80, 74, 93};
double result = 0; 
{
for(int x=0; x < int.length; x++){
result += score[x];
}
System.out.println(result/count)
```

Comment: `"but I can't seem to understand how to write code for averages..."` -- how would you do this on paper? Figure out the steps of your algorithm since the one for your program will be the same. Also, post your best attempt to solve this so this question looks to be more than a homework dump.

Comment: In the second for-loop, sum `score[x]` and divide that sum by `score.length`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008189/calculate-average-in-java?rq=1 and several others like this already have the answer

Answer (score 4):

```
double total=0;
double average=0;
for(int x = 0; x < score.length; ++x)
     total+=score[x];

average=total/score.length;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("Average Score:"+ average);
```

What you didn't understand?